# TextBlock-only window in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I would like to create a WPF window that really doesn't have any appearence except for the single `TextBlock` control with transparent background. The final result would look like this:

[image: WPF Popup TextBlock]

How can I create such a "ghost" window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with the following:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="50" Width="200" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent"> 
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextClock" FontSize..... etc....> 
    </TextBlock> 
</Window>
```